# Why does the new version of the Top Display LCD screen IST3020-TX display jumbled pixels?

Tags: arduino, iot, lcd

The new IST3020-TX displays jumbled pixels instead of the OTI Saturn 6000 logo. The older version IST3020 displays perfectly. I need help identifying the problem with the newer versions and possible solutions to this problem.
I have attached photos of the two displays
[Jambled LCD screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRAmN.jpg)
[Expected display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daB83.jpg)